# Developing a photo tagging application (with possibiltiy of tagging unlimited tags)

Tags: facebook, tagging, photo-tagging

Developing a facebook application similar to:
http://www.fostersartofchilling.com/introducing-strong

Their is an image that will be relieved if all the pixels are tagged.
Hovering on any pixel on the image previews the thumbnail of the user photo and name.

I tried using fb graph api, but we all know fb has policy set regarding no. of people that can be tagged on an image (50 person).

Please Help on this,
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

if there is a policy and facebook has limited this at the api level, it is very likely that this cannot be done.

and even assuming you can do tagging at the pixel level, the no. of tags would still be limited.

Comment: Now i know why i am getting tagged everyday with advertisements ug.

Comment: @eddy: if u check the link i referred: http://www.fostersartofchilling.com/introducing-strong

it has implemented this concept...
ur answer will contradict this once u see it

thanks for the reply :)